# How the matter and radiation densities of universe can be calculated?

Tags: cosmology, universe, density

*Barbara Ryden* gave somehow detailed and intuitive calculation in *Article 5.1* of *Introduction to Cosmology* but skipped detail on some values. 
I don't know, it's good or not but I'm adding snaps from the book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead. @puppetsock presumably the title "How the matter and radiation densities of universe can be calculated?" but it could use some more details; it's rather broad.